# How do I cast shadows from 3D Objects in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d, 3d-analyst

I would like to cast shadows from my 3D objects in ArcScene onto the surface and other objects. (Much like I can in SketchUp).  Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Jakub, did you figure out how to cast shadows in ArcScene? I am trying to do the same thing with Buildings on the ground surface and other buildings. Thank you! - Lucas

Comment: Hi Lucas. Not possible with ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Shading for TINs is a hillshade illumination option on the Layer Properties dialog box, Symbology tab. **Shading can be enabled individually for each layer in the ArcScene document.**

[image]

Though ArcScene is the not the best 3D Software to work with with 3D rendering.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of these controls but they only adjust illumination. I would like to cast shadow from buildings for example onto other buildings and the ground surface.